# Confusion in understanding Custom Search API Access limit

Tags: google-custom-search

**First of all i am very sorry because this question could appear nonconstructive or too localized to some moderators**

I am just confuse with custom search API query limit's as i have read that it is free upto 100 queries and charge $5/1000 queries up to 10,000 i just want make me sure on this.

1) Is this limit for API call lets take an example  i.e. I search with a keyword 'watch' and it returns 2000 results to me with only first 10 results in the object this is my first API call and when i again call the API for next 10 results it is going to make another API and count it 2 query out of 100 free?

Please read the above questions carefully i just want to know that reading through the pagination will  make query quota to exceed the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each API call is counted as 1, so if 2 pagination requests are made they are 2 calls.